# ¿Cómo hacer que al entrar en una pagina me muestre solo ciertos elementos identificados con un ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Hola comunidad espero estén todos bien, quería consultar algo, así como dice el titulo quiero que yo al seleccionar la opciones dentro de varios **selectbox** (**combobox o dropdown** como quieran) es que estos me muestren solo los elementos previamente identificados con un **id** en otra pagina. les dejo el código para que me entiendan mejor.

```
<div class="contenedor">
<form class="selectform" name="form1" target="_blank">
<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
<select id="mySelect" name="sitio">
<option disabled selected class="ph">Gestión</option>
<option value="sulmybienesraices.com/lista-venta/">Venta</option>
<option value="sulmybienesraices.com/lista-alquiler/">Alquiler</option>
<option value="sulmybienesraices.com/lista-anticretico/">Anticrético</option>
<option value="sulmybienesraices.com/lista-permuta/">Permuta</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<div class="contenedor">
<form class="selectform" name="form2" target="_blank">
<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
<select id="mySelect" name="id">
<option disabled selected class="ph">Ciudad</option>
<option value="ventacasa">La Paz</option>
<option value="depaanti">Santa Cruz</option>
<option value="ventacasa">Tajira</option>
<option value="localanti">Cochabamba</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<input class="btnsub" id="btn1" type="button" value="Ir" onClick="javascript:abreSitio()">
```

**Y AHORA EL SCRIPT **

```
<script>
function abreSitio(){
var web = document.form1.sitio.options[document.form1.sitio.selectedIndex].value;
var identificador = document.form2.id.options[document.form1.sitio.selectedIndex].value;
window.open(web+"#"+identificador, '_blank', '');
};
</script>
```

Literalmente esta funcionando lo que ya esta escrito pero quiero que al cargar la pagina solo se me muestren los elementos que tengan el id de del segundo select que esta representado como un value pero al ejecutar el script el navegador lo abre como un ancla

Comment: Para ello debes pasar el id como parámetro y no como ancla, pero no solo eso, sino que la página receptora sea capaz de interpretar ese parámetro y que solo te muestre los valores relacionados con el id pasado como parámetro.  Incluye el código de dicha página en tu pregunta pulsando [edit] para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: La pagina receptora esta en wordpress, más sin embargo ya logre resolver de alguna manera jajaja gracias igual